# Overriding non-open instance swift for a custom made view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a custom made view controller and I'm trying to add functions for a UIviewControllerTransitioningDelegate on a custom view controller, and I'm having trouble. Here is the code. I'm getting an "overriding non-open instance method outside of its dining module error" at "open override func animationController(forPresented" and "open override func animationController(forDismissed". Heres an image of the error.

[image: Error Image]

```
import UIKit
import ColorMatchTabs

class MainPageViewController: ColorMatchTabsViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ShoppingCart: TKTransitionSubmitButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Settings: TKTransitionSubmitButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        titleLabel.font = UIFont.navigationTitleFont()
        // to hide bottom button remove the following line
        popoverViewController = MainPopOverViewController()
        popoverViewController?.delegate = self

        dataSource = self
        reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func SettingsButton(_ button: TKTransitionSubmitButton) {
        button.animate(0, completion: { () -> () in
            let secondVC = SettingsViewController()
            secondVC.transitioningDelegate = self
            self.present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
    }

    @IBAction func ShoppingCartButton(_ button: TKTransitionSubmitButton) {
        button.animate(0, completion: { () -> () in

        })
    }

    open override func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return TKFadeInAnimator(transitionDuration: 0.5, startingAlpha: 0.8)
    }

    open override func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return nil
    }

}

extension MainPageViewController: ColorMatchTabsViewControllerDataSource {

    func numberOfItems(inController controller: ColorMatchTabsViewController) -> Int {
        return TabItemsProvider.items.count
    }

    func tabsViewController(_ controller: ColorMatchTabsViewController, viewControllerAt index: Int) -> UIViewController {
        return StubContentViewControllersProvider.viewControllers[index]
    }

    func tabsViewController(_ controller: ColorMatchTabsViewController, titleAt index: Int) -> String {
        return TabItemsProvider.items[index].title
    }

    func tabsViewController(_ controller: ColorMatchTabsViewController, iconAt index: Int) -> UIImage {
        return TabItemsProvider.items[index].normalImage
    }

    func tabsViewController(_ controller: ColorMatchTabsViewController, hightlightedIconAt index: Int) -> UIImage {
        return TabItemsProvider.items[index].highlightedImage
    }

    func tabsViewController(_ controller: ColorMatchTabsViewController, tintColorAt index: Int) -> UIColor {
        return TabItemsProvider.items[index].tintColor
    }

}

extension MainPageViewController: PopoverViewControllerDelegate {

    func popoverViewController(_ popoverViewController: PopoverViewController, didSelectItemAt index: Int) {
        selectItem(at: index)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Define `ColorMatchTabsViewController`  methods with `open`.
A open class will be both usable and subclassable. Similarly, a public member will only be usable by other modules, but not overridable. An open member will be both usable and overridable.

so define `animationController` and `animationController` open in ColorMatchTabsViewController extension. Default they defined as public.

Comment: how would i do that

Comment: where would that go. is it an extension

Comment: I need to define mainviewcontroller. what would that be defined as

Comment: sail what would i do

Comment: I guess you need to define ColorMatchTabsViewController open Because An open class will be subclassable.

Comment: can you show me where id put it in my original swift file. thats what I'm confused about

Comment: // MARK: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return TKFadeInAnimator(transitionDuration: 0.5, startingAlpha: 0.8)
    }
    
    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return nil
    }

Comment: but i'm having trouble